# Blank slides at beginning of sections with Philex/Linguex and Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, linguex

I use the Philex package for linguistic examples. I've found that if I load it with Beamer I get a blank slide at the beginning of each section (see my MWE). This isn't just a Philex problem, because the same thing happens with Linguex. (Philex is based on Linguex.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Philex MWE}
\author{Thomas Hodgson}

\usepackage{philex}
% \usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section one} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_one}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Frame one}

Some text.

\end{frame}

% section section_one (end)

\section{Section two} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_two}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Frame two}

Some more text

\end{frame}

% section section_two (end)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 4.0 of `linguex` added some code to fix an odd spacing problem with `beamer`.  I suspect that source of this problem was subsequently fixed in `beamer` and now the fix in `linguex` is causing the problem.  This has been fixed in version 4.3 of `linguex` but if you have an older version of the package, you can simply undo the fix using the `etoolbox` package.

**Answer for older versions of `linguex`**

I've added two lines to your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\patchcmd{\label}{\strut}{}{}{}}
```

Here's the complete code that now works as it should.  I tested with `linguex`, since I'm not familiar with the `philtex` commands.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Philex MWE}
\author{Thomas Hodgson}

%\usepackage{philex}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{\patchcmd{\label}{\strut}{}{}{}}
\begin{document}

\section{Section one} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_one}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Frame one}
\ex.
\a. Some text.

\end{frame}

% section section_one (end)

\section{Section two} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_two}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Frame two}

Some more text

\end{frame}

% section section_two (end)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. It also works with philex.

Comment: It seems that the problem doesn't arise with the latest version of beamer.

Comment: @Tom `linguex` has also been updated to fix the problem, so unless you are still using the old version, it's `linguex` that has adapted.